# Add short names for micromamba (conda) environments

Tags: conda, mamba

I was using conda. Now I want to use micromamba. When I run `conda env list` I see

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3
circle_sum-env           /Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3/envs/circle_sum-env
fdfdpy                   /Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3/envs/fdfdpy
...etc...
```

When I run `micromamba env list`  I see

```
  Name  Active  Path                                                
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  base          /Users/tomsturges/micromamba                        
                /Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3                     
                /Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3/envs/circle_sum-env 
                /Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3/envs/fdfdpy         
  ....etc...
```

I want to have short names for my environments, the same as conda does automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just mamba? I still think of micromamba as a devops/sysadmin utility - not the frontend for an end user.

Comment: @merv ok fair enough. no good reason, other than I inherited the system that I'm working on like that. thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Since micromamba has a way easier installation process (just put the executable on your PATH and add `eval "$(/path/to/micromamba shell hook -s bash)"` in your bashrc), it also makes sense to use it as an end user. Also, it can nowadays do almost everything that conda can do.

Answer (score 2):

This is because micromamba has a different root prefix by default. micromamba only shows the short names for environments inside of your root prefix.

You can either work only with micromamba, then your environments get installed into `/Users/tomsturges/micromamba/envs/env-name` (which requires you to recreate the environments) or you can change the env variable `MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX` to `/Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3`.

```
root@f27d32b0ffd6:/# conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /opt/conda
testenv                  /opt/conda/envs/testenv
                         /root/micromamba/envs/testenv2

root@f27d32b0ffd6:/# micromamba env list
  Name      Active  Path
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                    /opt/conda
                    /opt/conda/envs/testenv
  base              /root/micromamba
  testenv2          /root/micromamba/envs/testenv2
root@f27d32b0ffd6:/# MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX=/opt/conda micromamba env list
  Name     Active  Path
───────────────────────────────────────────────────
  base             /opt/conda
  testenv          /opt/conda/envs/testenv
                   /root/micromamba/envs/testenv2
```

(in your example, `/opt/conda` corresponds to `/Users/tomsturges/opt/anaconda3` and `/root/micromamba` corresponds to `/Users/tomsturges/micromamba`)

Comment: Thank you that works :) 
Now how do I change the prefix permanently?
I guess I need a `.mambarc` but I don't know where to put it

Comment: You can set the `MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX` to point to a specific location by adding this statement to your `~/.zshrc` (assuming you're using ZSH on macOS): `export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX="/path/to/root/prefix"`.

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) for more information